# Folders comparison so vital security information is not deleted

Tags: filesystems

There are files in two separate folders, one folder has more files than the other but a large number of the files are identical. 
They take a lot of space, so I want to just keep the files in the second folder that the first folder doesn't have.

How do I do that, without having to go file by file?

Comment: Please move your question to serverfault.

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: In Linux you can use `stat` to compare file sizes and modification times: if these are identical, there is a pretty good chance that the contents are also identical, though you cannot be absolutely sure without a full byte-by-byte comparison, such as `cmp` does.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the filenames are identical in both folders, and you have a Bash shell, run this command **from within the second folder**:

```
grep -Ff <(find /path/to/first/folder/*  -printf "%f\n") <(find *  -printf "%f\n") | xargs -0 rm
```

The second command searches for all files with the same name and `rm`s it. Be careful while deleting. You may want to run the command without `| xargs -0 rm` first, just to see what files are being deleted.

Comment: Piping to `rm` doesn't work, you need `xargs` or `parallel` or similar; the first requires care if any filename contains whitespace, quotes, or backslash, and both fail if any filename contains newline (which is unusual). `grep -f` may not be optimized for large number of strings (even with `-F`) so `awk` or `perl` hash lookup may be faster (for data that fits in memory, but that's true for `grep -f` also)

Comment: Good point @dave_thompson_085. Updated to use xargs. You're right in that this scales quite poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives for Windows are DOS findstr and fc (file compare).
I don't know what the exact command would look like, if someone does please comment.